# How can I get a plain list of computer names on the network from "net view"?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am using the `net view` command. It displays the users on the network in big and ugly UPPERCASE letters and has columns etc., for example:

```
Server Name            Remark    
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
\\ADRIAN-PC
\\MARK-PC

The command completed successfully.
```

Is there a way for me just to display the computer names on the network?

```
-Adrian
-Mark
```

I'd like to have the output without the lines and columns. Maybe with a `findstr` command.

Comment: What do you need that for? Notice that not all computers will have names like `SOMEONE'S-PC`.

Answer (score 2):

```
(for /f %a in ('net view ^| findstr/b \\\\') do @echo %a)
```

You cannot (or should not) remove the `-PC` suffix, since you are not listing usernames – you are listing *computer* names, and the suffix is *part of the computer name*.

Comment: Sorry We South Africans spell "welldone" with 2 L's. Thanks for the code I'll test it out now! :)

Comment: So would it work if I had 5 users on the network?

Comment: And is it possible for me to save it into a varible i.e for /f %%i in ('net view^|findstr /b \\') do set networkuser=%%i

Comment: Or if there are no users on the network. echo NO USERS FOUND

Comment: It doesn't list users. It lists computers.

Answer (score 1):

Net View displays domain/workgroup resources, i.e server and PC resources. It doesn’t give an accurate overview of machines on the network as that’s not it’s complete role. You need to use ARP –a to get this and translate them to their hostnames.

Comment: I don't think `arp -a` is the same (even if I pipe the IP addresses into an ip->hostname translator like nslookup), it only shows me about 10 IP addresses, and I know there are about 30 machines on the network right now (that show up in "My Network Places" anyway, probably even a few more than that). -- It's an NT domain if it matters/makes more tools available. -- How do I get a list of host names (or even IPs) of all the machines on the current network? (Or even subnet for that matter.)

Comment: You either write a script that will be all the possible hosts on the network, use ARP but as you can see it's limited to the amount of hosts the computer actually knows about at that time.

Or you connect to the gateways and see their connections/DHCP bindings etc